# Why does `OneOrMore` fails with more than one expression in pyparsing?

Tags: python, grammar, text-parsing, pyparsing

Ok, I put together a parser to parse expressions like

```
abc def ghi LONG|SHORT 12345

----^------ ----^----- --^--
 A: alphas  B: choice  C: num
```

The parser written in [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) looks like this:

```
a = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphas)).setName("PRT_A")
b = pp.Or(['LONG','SHORT']).setName("PRT_B")
c = pp.Word(pp.nums).setName("PRT_C")
expr = a('A') + b('B') + c('C')
```

When I feed "something said SHORT 13" into it:

```
res = expr.parseString("something said SHORT 13")
```

I get the error:

```
ParseException: 
Expected {"LONG" ^ "SHORT"} (at char 21), (line:1, col:22)
"something said SHORT >!<13"
```

Why? I thought `OneOrMore` should add up all the words until a LONG|SHORT choice comes...

Comment: @user2357112 I have simplified the question to only contain the lookahead problem - makes the question a lot clearer and more valuable top others, I think. Would you mind updating the (now accepted) answer accordingly (i.e. taking out the stuff about `Combine`)?

Comment: Answer updated, but you should also update the error message in the question. The version without `Combine` should produce an error at a later location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `pp.Word(pp.alphas)` includes both `"LONG"` and `"SHORT"`, preventing `b` from matching. You need to prevent it from matching those keywords, such as with a negative lookahead:

```
b = pp.Or(['LONG','SHORT']).setName("PRT_B")
a = pp.OneOrMore(~b + pp.Word(pp.alphas)).setName("PRT_A")
```

or with the `stopOn` option for `OneOrMore`:

```
b = pp.Or(['LONG','SHORT']).setName("PRT_B")
a = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphas), stopOn=b).setName("PRT_A")
```

Comment: The point is not the Combine, but the OneOrMore. The same problem appears without the surrounding Combine. (Maybe I should get rid of the Combine for the example... )

Comment: @halloleo: No, it just turns out you have two bugs, the Combine bug and a second bug. If you take out the Combine, you get a different error.

Comment: Unfortunately, ignore() is used to include expressions that are ignorable, in the same way that whitespace is ignorable - usually comments. But your description of the second bug is dead on. To address it, OneOrMore has a stopOn option to stop matching when an expression, which would ordinarily match the OneOrMore expression, is seen. Also, Combine is also questionable as you say - maybe Group is more appropriate.

Comment: To follow your suggestion of *ignoring*, in this case, use a negative lookahead: `a = ~b + pp.Word(pp.alphas)`

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I understand that the problem is that a matches  b. And the ".ignore(b" solution makes sense to me (will test it tomorrow). However using instead the negative lookahead: `a = ~b + pp.Word(pp.alphas)`  does not make sense to me.

Comment: Again, `a.ignore(b)` is *not* correct. The way negative lookahead works is that every time pyparsing will try to match the a expression, it will first makes sure that what it is looking at does *not* match the b expression. Like this, to parse a list of numbers, ending with a number of all zeroes: `(OneOrMore(~Word('0') + Word(nums)) + Word('0')).parseString("123 456 000")` - while iterating over the input string, before matching a `Word(nums)`, the OneOrMore will first check that it is not looking at a word of all zeroes. The new form is `OneOrMore(Word(nums), stopOn=Word('0')) + Word('0')`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Ah, thanks for the correction. `ignore` [came up](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/share/view/2797153) when I searched for `pyparsing keywords`, trying to figure out how people get pyparsing to not treat keywords as identifiers, but I see it produces results like `pp.Word(pp.alphas).ignore('ASDF')` matching the `'FDSA'` in `'ASDFFDSA'`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire user2357112: Works a treat with `stopOn=b` or `~b +`. Thanks.